# I need to store the previous value of a variable in another variable

Tags: javascript

I'm making a dice rolling game and I need to make it that if you roll twice 6 in a row that you lose all your points. So I thought you need to make a variable that stores the previous value of the variable, but I just can't figure out how to do that. Here's the function, I need the store the previous value of the variable 'dice' all the way at the top of the function:

```js
document.querySelector('.btn-roll').addEventListener('click', function() {
    if(gamePlaying) {
        //1.Random number
        var dice = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
        //2. Display the result
        var diceDOM = document.querySelector('.dice');
        diceDOM.style.display = 'block';
        diceDOM.src = 'dice-' + dice + '.png';
    
        //3 Update the round score IF the rolled number was NOT a 1
        if (dice !== 1){
            roundScore += dice;
            document.querySelector('#current-' + activePlayer).textContent = roundScore;
        } else {
            togglePlayer();
        } 
    } else {
        alert("Start a new game!!!");
    }
    
   
});
```

Comment: You already must be doing something similar. You are keeping a 'roundScore' variable. That variable keeps the score of previous dice rolls. So what you want to do is not much different from that.

Comment: Snippets should be able to be run without errors, otherwise that defeats the purpose of making a snippet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hopefully the following will help:

```js
var previousDice = 0;
document.querySelector('.btn-roll').addEventListener('click', function() {
 if(gamePlaying) {
  //1.Random number
  var dice = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
  
  if (dice === previousDice === 6) {
   // all your points are gone
  }
  //2. Display the result
  var diceDOM = document.querySelector('.dice');
  diceDOM.style.display = 'block';
  diceDOM.src = 'dice-' + dice + '.png';
    
  //3 Update the round score IF the rolled number was NOT a 1
  if (dice !== 1){
   roundScore += dice;
   document.querySelector('#current-' + activePlayer).textContent = roundScore;
  } else {
   togglePlayer();
  }
  previousDice = dice;
 } else {
  previousDice = 0;
  alert("Start a new game!!!");
 }
});
```

Comment: Is `if (dice === previousDice === 6)` valid javascript? `===` is left associative so this calculates to `(dice === previousDice) === 6` and that boils down to comparing a boolean to an integer and that is always `false` using `===`.

Comment: yes it is valid javascript and means all three values should be the same (including data type). The 0 for previousDice is just the initial state so that you  know that if it's 0 there is no previous value

Comment: @rioV8 Is right, `dice === previousDice === 6` will always equate to false. It should be `dice === previousDice && previousDice === 6`.

Comment: This can be changed to 
if (dice == previousDice) && dice == 6 {
     // all your points are gone
}

Comment: @llamacorn it is bad practice to use the `==` and `!=`. Never use it, it will lead to all kinds of obscure and hard to find bugs due to implicit type conversions.

Comment: @rioV8 Using `==` and `!=` is not bad practice all of the time, it's how you use them that determines whether or not it's bad practice. Just because it's bad practice _most_ of the time doesn't mean it's bad practice _all_ of the time.

Comment: I used (dice === 6 && previousDice === 6) that also worked, but thanks alot for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a temporal variable (`previousRoll`) an check in every roll if `previouosRoll === 6 && dice === 6` (previous and current roll are equal to 6). If so, do your logic, otherwise

```js
// mock
var gamePlaying = true;
var roundScore = 0;
var activePlayer = 1;

function togglePlayer() {}
// end mock

var previousRoll;

document.querySelector('.btn-roll').addEventListener('click', function() {
  if (gamePlaying) {
    //1.Random number
    var dice = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
    console.log(dice);
    if (previousRoll === 6 && dice === 6) {
      //if you roll twice 6 in a row you lose all your points
      dice = 0;
      console.log('lost your points')
    }
    previousRoll = dice; // this will reset previousRoll too in case it was a double-six

    //2. Display the result
    var diceDOM = document.querySelector('.dice');
    diceDOM.style.display = 'block';
    diceDOM.src = 'dice-' + dice + '.png';

    //3 Update the round score IF the rolled number was NOT a 1
    if (dice === 0) {
      console.log('your logic when points should be reset')
    } else if (dice !== 1) {
      roundScore += dice;
      document.querySelector('#current-' + activePlayer).textContent = roundScore;
    } else {
      togglePlayer();
    }
  } else {
    alert("Start a new game!!!");
  }
});
```

```html
<button class="btn-roll">Roll</button> <-- click until you get two 6 in a row :) and see the console

<div class="dice"></div>

<div id="current-1"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can do it in simple way

```
var role_count = 0
if (dice == 6 && role_count < 3) {
    role_count++;
  console.log("role count: "+role_count);
  if (role_count == 3){
    role_count = 0;
    dice = 0;
    console.log('reset');
    // change player turn
  }
}
else {
    role_count = 0;
}
```

Corrected: [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/thezeeshantariq/0y6vsrzj/5/)

Comment: This will permit up to 3 times the `6` value while the OP asked for _... if you roll **twice** 6 in a row..._

Comment: when the dice will be rolled for the third time, the condition will become false, and `else` block will run

Comment: No, **it will not**, see this [**jsfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/lealceldeiro/kujv023c/8/)... this is using your logic except for a `console.log` I put after `dice = 0;`... Open the devtools and see how it beahvies :)

Comment: I am sorry, I have edited my answer. You can check it now in dev tools.

Answer (score 0):

I found it! You guys really helped me, turns out I had to declare that variable at the end of the function so It's not refreshing when the new dice is declared! Thank you so much guys! Here's the code:

```js
var lastDice;

document.querySelector('.btn-roll').addEventListener('click', function() {
    if(gamePlaying) {
        //1.Random number
        var dice = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
        
        if(dice === 6 && lastDice === 6) {
             //Score is lost 
        };
        //2. Display the result
        var diceDOM = document.querySelector('.dice');
        diceDOM.style.display = 'block';
        diceDOM.src = 'dice-' + dice + '.png';
    
        //3 Update the round score IF the rolled number was NOT a 1
        if (dice !== 1){
            roundScore += dice;
            document.querySelector('#current-' + activePlayer).textContent = roundScore;
        } else {
            togglePlayer();
        } 
        lastDice = dice;
        
    } else {
        alert("Start a new game!!!");
    }
    
   
});
```